# use async auto as wrapper

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

My synchronous code is near thousand of lines. I want to divide them to some groups and put it in [async.auto](https://github.com/caolan/async) (one group is one function in async.auto). Each function has the name. I do that because I want to make it easy for other people to do maintain in the future. Code is divide to group so they will easy to understand. I want to know does async.auto cause performance loss comparing with when I don't use it

```
do some stuff;
do some stuff;
do some stuff;
...
do some stuff;
```

I want to change to below:

```
async.auto({
   do_A: function(cb){
      do some stuff;
      do some stuff;
   },
   do_B: ['do_A', function(cb, result){
      do some stuff with result;
      do some stuff with result;
   }]
}, function(err, result){

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely be able to divide it up and put it as separate functions into async.auto but often with large blocks of synchronous code there is a lot of coupling between different sections of the code without you realising. My advice is to very carefully split it up, testing each time you create a new group and commit the change to SCM (e.g. git) before beginning the next change. This way when you discover problems you can go back and find out where you introduced it.

I don't know enough to say what the performance impact would be but I would think it would be minimal. Your best bet (as with any performance question) is to test it in a profiler. You won't get any performance *benefits* either unless you let it run some of the functions out of order. If every block depends on the previous one then it will all just be run in sequence.

Comment: what do you mean when saying "test it in a profiler". Profiler is  testing tool. Sorry, my english is not good

Comment: A profiler will allow you to measure how quickly the code executes, how much memory it uses, etc. It's very difficult to accurately estimate how the performance of a piece of code will change when you alter it, so the safest way to find out is to use a profiler before and after the change and compare the results.